# Website's video displays in different sizes in different browsers

Tags: wordpress, youtube

Here is the website.

http://www.allinonewebshop.co.uk/

Homepage video is displaying in different sizes in Chrome,Firefox and Internet Explorer.What can I do?

Thank you

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><object width="500" height="300" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" /><param name="src" value="//www.youtube.com/v/dTcUOPYCwD0?version=3&amp;hl=en_GB" /><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /><embed width="500" height="300" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="//www.youtube.com/v/dTcUOPYCwD0?version=3&amp;hl=en_GB" allowFullScreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" /></object></p>
```

Comment: can you post your code you are using in video

Comment: Code is too long.How can I add it?

Comment: just the youtube code you are using

Comment: I've attached it to my main post.please check

Comment: Did you check that @ anstrangel0ver?

Comment: you use fitVids.js pluging to adjust with to max of window, it causes differences between browsers.

Comment: michal  is right on this although you have given width and height to the youtube object its not taking it, remove the scrit to double check it if its causing the problem your js jquery.fitvids.min.js. this js does work in iexplorer. now you know the problem you can dig into jquery.fitvids.min.js js to get fixed.

Comment: Yeah I'll try.But it doesn't work in Chrome as well.I've changed the video size but it's not working either.

Comment: Need some more help friends.Please...